# What is difference between lift and elevator and hoist?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering

I am very confused by the three terms:lift and elevator and hoist

Are they all technically same thing or different??

Answer (score 3):

In terms of moving objects between levels, then not much.

But in terms of moving people, then lift and elevator are the English and American terms while a hoist is for goods only.

Answer (score 0):

**Elevator** has a closed cab,

[image: Elevator]

**Lift** has an open cab,

[image: Lift]

**Hoist** has no cab.

[image]

Comment: What you show as an elevator is also called a lift in some countries... And the second image what you have labelled "lift" is also called a hydraulic platform or (mobile) scissor table...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. "Lift" is used in England and "elevator" in America for the same term in public. But in technical terms, "cab" determines the difference between them. Figures are given just for example. There are lots of different types of lifts and elevators as well.